# How to change output of a certain Pods field?

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I have two pods: `course` and `teacher`.

Each `course` has a `teacher`.

I use shortcodes in order to build a form to define new `course`:

```
[pods name='course' form='1' fields='name, teacher' ]
```

When defining a new `course`, the user can choose the `teacher` for this `course`.

By default, the `name` of the `teacher` is displayed in a drop down list. I wonder if I can change the output of the `teachers` in the drop down list.

For example, in addition to the `name` I want to display a certain field, such as `location` of the `teacher` in the drop down list.

Is this possible using the built-in shortcodes of Pods 2?

---

**Update:**

Following the instructions of Scott, I solved the problem. I wrote the solution into the comment section but formating was lost. Below, I put the code again:

```
function pods_teacher_pick_data($data, $name, $value, $options, $pod, $id){
    if ($name == "pods_field_teachers") {
        foreach ($data as $id => &$value) {
            $p = pods('teacher', $id);
            $name = $p->display('name');
            $city = $p->display('profile.city.name');
            $value = $name . ' - ' . $city;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

add_filter('pods_field_pick_data', 'pods_teacher_pick_data', 1, 6);
```

Comment: This is plugin of someking using shortcodes. Without code nobody will help you :(

Comment: You can edit the podsmcs code to fit to Your needs, but its quite of a long story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not built in yet, but you can take over the data output using the filter: pods_field_pick_data

```
$data = apply_filters( 'pods_field_pick_data', $data, $name, $value, $options, $pod, $id );
```

Adding a filter to that filter should give you the ability to change what appears in the drop-down, or other relationship input types.

Edit: I just added a similar filter for filtering the autocomplete data too.

```
$pick_data = apply_filters( 'pods_field_pick_data_ajax', array(), $field[ 'name' ], null, $field, $pod, 0, $data );
```

$data in this array is actually the fully setup PodsData object

**EDIT (02/07/2013):**

In Pods 2.3, I've added a quick function that should streamline adding custom relationship objects. This is preferrer over overriding an existing relationship or using the custom simple definition dynamically. Pretty easy to use, check it out at https://github.com/pods-framework/pods/issues/1033

```
$options = array(
    'group' => 'Special Relationships', // Whatever you want the selection group to be, defaults to label
    'simple' => false, // Whether this field is related by strings or integer IDs, integer IDs get stored in wp_podsrel, strings are stored in the field itself either serialized (meta-based) or json encoded (table-based)
    'data' => array( // Custom define the items to select from manually
        1 => 'Gravity Form 1',
        2 => 'Gravity Form 2'
    ),
    'data_callback' => 'get_custom_gravity_forms_list', // Provide a callback function to call to define the data (instead of setting 'data' above)
    'value_to_label_callback' => 'get_custom_gravity_forms_list', // Provide a callback function to define the data when called through PodsField_Pick::value_to_label
    'simple_value_callback' => 'get_custom_gravity_forms_list' // Provide a callback function to define the data when called through PodsField_Pick::simple_value
);

pods_register_related_object( 'gravity-form', 'Gravity Forms', $options );
```

Comment: Is there any example of using that filter, so I can get an idea on how to use this?

Comment: I defined a filter function: `pods_teacher_pick_data($data, $name, $value, $options, $pod, $id)`. `$data` array holds `id` and `name` values of the `teachers`. But `$pod`, and `$id` variables are `null`. So it is not possible, to access any other field of `teacher`.

Comment: Right, no other fields are retrieved from the database on purpose, to keep things light-weight. You'll want to use the 'id' to pull in the data from the teacher, then replace the 'name' with whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I did it. Here is the filter function I wrote if someone may need it:

    function pods_teacher_pick_data($data, $name, $value, $options, $pod, $id){
        if ($name == "pods_field_teachers") {
            foreach ($data as $id => &$value) {
                $p = pods('teacher', $id);
                $name = $p->display('name');
                $city = $p->display('profile.city.name');
                $value = $name . ' - ' . $city;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    add_filter('pods_field_pick_data', 'pods_teacher_pick_data', 1, 6);

Comment: Just added some cool info about a recent feature completed for Pods 2.3!

Answer (score 0):

For ajax, it seems need to use a bit different filter pods_field_pick_data_ajax_items like this:

```
function pods_teacher_pick_data_ajax_items($items, $name, $null, $field, $pod, $id){
    if ($name == "pods_meta_categorie" || $name == 'categorie') {
        foreach ($items as &$item) {
            $id = $item['id'];
            $value = $item['text'];
            $p = pods('dvd_categories', $id);
            $code = $p->display('code');
            $item['text'] .= ' - ' . $code;
        }
    }
    return $items;
}

add_filter('pods_field_pick_data_ajax_items', 'pods_teacher_pick_data_ajax_items', 1, 6);
```

Note different structure of arrays $data and $items.
Filter pods_teacher_pick_data_ajax looks very strange and useless to me as  it doesnt accept $data array.